# VLC reverts to first 'Audio Device' after each track

Tags: audio, bluetooth, vlc-media-player

I am trying to play a folder of music tracks with VLC on Raspberry Pi OS (Debian).

I am using a shorcut with a shell script to start things (as this needs to be point and click-ish for a kiosk type setup) and I believe it is not possible to define the output audio device in the command line.

So, when VLC starts up I select the correct audio device (a bluetooth speaker that is confirmed connected) and audio plays as expected.

However, when each track finishes and the next starts the audio device reverts to the first in the list which is internal audio... (Built-in Audio Analogue Stereo).

How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik end of the first line in the question... Raspberry Pi OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved!

The trick was to right-click the speaker icon in the top right of the desktop and select profiles.

In there turn off all other audio devices - the 'Built-in Analogue' and the 'Built-in Digital' - leaving only the Bluetooth device enabled.

That way there is no other device for VLC to switch back to.

It's maybe more of a workaround than a fix, but it's resolved the issue for my use case.

Comment: It's just an workaround indeed.